# How to use tf.nn.crelu in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, activation-function

I am trying different activation functions in my simple neural network.

It does not matter using `tf.nn.relu`, `tf.nn.sigmoid`,... the network does what it should do.

But if I am using `tf.nn.crelu`, I have a dimension error.

It returns something like `[max, min]` and the width dimension is twice bigger. 
What do I have to do? Fitting the following weights and biases to the output of `crelu`?

Comment: CReLu Concatenates a ReLU which selects only the positive part of the activation with a ReLU which selects only the negative part of the activation. Note that as a result this non-linearity doubles the depth of the activations. You can read more here. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/crelu

Comment: yes, this it what it does. but how to use it?

Comment: Can you check the below link, it contains an example implementation(uses crelu from chainer but it is very similar/same as tensorflow) https://programtalk.com/vs2/python/10099/chainer/tests/chainer_tests/functions_tests/activation_tests/test_crelu.py/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, if you're building the network manually, you need to adjust the dimensions of the following layer to match `tf.nn.crelu` output. In this sense, `tf.nn.crelu` is *not* interchangeable with `tf.nn.relu`, `tf.nn.elu`, etc.

The situation is simpler if you use a high-level API, e.g. [tensorflow slim](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/08/tf-slim-high-level-library-to-define.html). In this case, the layer functions are taking care of matching dimensions, so you can replace `tf.nn.relu` easily with `tf.nn.crelu` in *code*. However, keep in mind that the network is silently becoming twice as big.

Here's an example:

```py
with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                    activation_fn=tf.nn.crelu,
                    normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
                    normalizer_params={'is_training': is_training, 'decay': 0.95}):
    conv1 = slim.conv2d(x_image, 16, [5, 5], scope='conv1')
    pool1 = slim.max_pool2d(conv1, [2, 2], scope='pool1')
    conv2 = slim.conv2d(pool1, 32, [5, 5], scope='conv2')
    pool2 = slim.max_pool2d(conv2, [2, 2], scope='pool2')
    flatten = slim.flatten(pool2)
    fc = slim.fully_connected(flatten, 1024, scope='fc1')
    drop = slim.dropout(fc, keep_prob=keep_prob)
    logits = slim.fully_connected(drop, 10, activation_fn=None, scope='logits')
```

`slim.arg_scope` simply applies all provided arguments to the underlying layers, in particular `activation_fn`. Also note `activation_fn=None` in the last layer to fix the output dimension. Complete code can be [found here](https://github.com/soloice/mnist-bn/blob/master/mnist_bn.py).